# what's meaning of this mark ":=" in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I don't know
What's the meaning of this mark? := in MySQL
Um...
for example in Code.

```
  select @RN:=@RN+1 as no, ...
  from Employee
  where EmployeeNumber='stackoverflow'
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's referencing a bind variable. For example say it's PHP, that will replace that reference with a variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is binded variable. It will referenced later on while executing the query.

Answer (score 1):

For the query you've given, there is no effect in time you executed the query.

After the query executed, you can execute a query like this,

```
select @RN
```

This will give you the previous @RN value.

The variable @RN is initially 0, and you add up +1 every query.

That is, you will have **executed query count** in @RN variable anytime you want.

Comment: Actually @RN is initially NULL and unless you initialize it the query will return NULL's for that column. If it is initialized it will get incremented for each row and the result will have sequential integers in that column.

Comment: Yeah, you may right. I remember smt like 0, but it may be NULL. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It assigns a value to a variable. Same as the = operator in C style languages.

In this case you will get NULL's for that column unless you initialize @RN before you run the query (because NULL+1 returns NULL).

If you initialize it you will get sequential integers in the result.